# IS Elasticsearch Hadoop 7.10.0 compatible with Spark 3.0.1

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am trying to use Elasticsearch with Spark but I am getting some errors.

i use Spark 3.0.1 and Elasticsearch 7.10.0  and elasticsearch-hadoop 7.1.0
scala version 2.12

someone can help me ?

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
    at net.jgp.books.spark.ch08.ElasticsearchToDatasetApp.start(ElasticsearchToDatasetApp.java:42)
    at net.jgp.books.spark.ch08.ElasticsearchToDatasetApp.main(ElasticsearchToDatasetApp.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more```
````

Comment: the error message looks incomplete - can you post a complete traceback?

Comment: it seems like elasticsearch-hadoop 7.1.0  is using scala version 2.11 but spark use scala version 2.12 . even if i exclude  all dependecy from elasticsearch-hadoop 7.1.0 jar . i am still getting the problem.